# selenium c# mouse over actions function

Tags: c#, selenium

I have to mouse over a row to display a link that I need to click. I am able to mouse over the row and the link I need to click on is displayed but I can't click on it. Below is my code:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(), 'abc@gmail.com')]"));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            IWebElement delete = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(), 'Delete')]"));
            delete.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I gather that there is a menu that pops up when you hover over that first "element" IWebElement.  When using Java, I had a similar problem where a simple click() action on the menu item in that popup would not work.  I had to resort to using Javascript.  You could insert this line right after your code to retrieve the delete web element:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", delete);
```

I'm guessing that you could do something similar with C#

Comment: I've updated to point out that you can drop this line of code into your source, assuming the syntax works for C#)

Comment: After i mouse over abc@gmail.com a menu appears in the right right corner with edit, disable and delete links. I need to click on delete

Comment: Yes, this line of code tells Selenium to use javascript to click on the delete web element.